# PHP MongoDB driver equivalent for Mongo execute

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm having trouble finding what if any equivalent there is in the "new" MongoDB driver/library for the old driver's `execute` command. In this case, I just want to run `Math.random()`, and can't seem to figure out what command is equivalent. I saw http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php but I can't even figure out how to use it. Is it supposed to be run on the MongoDB\Client class?

Comment: I think it is executed on MongoClient `$db`. Do you have any code to share?

Comment: I tried running it on an instance of MongoClient and that didn't work. All the code I have was creating an instance of MongoClient and then trying `$mongo->execute('Math.random()')`.

Comment: it should be '$db->execute('Math.random()')'

Comment: But what is `$db` in this case? What is it an instance of?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it.

```
<?php
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(array('eval' => "Math.random()"));
$cursor = $manager->executeCommand('testDb', $command);

print_r($cursor->toArray());
?>
```

And here is the sample output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [retval] => 0.66910735880473
            [ok] => 1
        )

)
```

Checkout the [executeCommand](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executecommand.php) method of [Manager](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php) class for more details

Comment: Thanks, this helps clarify a lot!

Comment: Welcome @RhoVisions ! If you find this helpful, mark it as accepted so that others can find it helpful.